# Rename column names in DT in Shiny

Tags: shiny

Is there a way to rename column names in DT table in shiny. My original column names in the DT is as shown below

```
colnames(DT_table) <- c("AB", "BC", "CD")

##rename column names to (inside renderDT)
colnames(DT_table) <- c("AB", "New BC", "New CD")


    output$table <- DT::renderDT({           
        datatable(
            DT_table,
            rownames = F, 
            escape = FALSE,
        ) 
    })
```

Comment: just put the rename line within the renderDT

Comment: I tried . But didn get. Can u do it for me please?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the rename inside the server, outside the server or inside the `renderDT`. Not sure why this doesn't work for you. I do it outside the server since the data is static. Only do it inside the server if the data is changing based on user inputs, but it will work there too.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::DTOutput("table")
)

DT_table <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 11:20, c = 21:30)

colnames(DT_table) <- c("AB", "BC", "CD")

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$table <- DT::renderDT({ 

    ##rename column names to (inside renderDT)
    colnames(DT_table) <- c("AB", "New BC", "New CD")

    DT::datatable(
      DT_table,
      rownames = F, 
      escape = FALSE,
    ) 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Output]

You can place the new column names inside `renderDT()`, before you call `datatable()` and the output will show the column names from the `renderDT` call. See below:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::DTOutput("table")
)

DT_table <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 11:20, c = 21:30)

colnames(DT_table) <- c("AB", "BC", "CD")

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$table <- DT::renderDT({ 

    ##rename column names to (inside renderDT)
    colnames(DT_table) <- c("AB", "Changed BC", "Changed CD")

    DT::datatable(
      DT_table,
      rownames = F, 
      escape = FALSE,
    ) 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Great thank you. But is it not possible to rename column names inside renderDT function

Comment: It is, see the second part of my answer